# Select timediff between rows of 2 different columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to find the time difference between phonecalls in SQL. My sample data looks like

| name | call_start | call_finished |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:52:22.000 | 2021-05-21 10:52:25.000 |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 10:52:43.000 | 2021-05-21 10:53:10.000 |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 10:54:01.000 | 2021-05-21 10:54:01.000 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:53:48.000 | 2021-05-21 10:53:51.000 |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 10:54:14.000 | 2021-05-21 10:56:31.000 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:56:33.000 | 2021-05-21 10:56:38.000 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:58:13.000 | 2021-05-21 10:58:52.000 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 11:00:37.000 | 2021-05-21 11:00:37.000 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 11:03:14.000 | 2021-05-21 11:04:06.000 |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 11:05:20.000 | 2021-05-21 11:05:20.000 |

I want to find the difference between `call_finished` and `call_start` for each `name` such that I get a column `Time_since_last_call` is generated.

| name | call start | call_finished | Time_since_last_call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:52:22.000 | 2021-05-21 10:52:25.000 | Null |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 10:52:43.000 | 2021-05-21 10:53:10.000 | Null |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 10:54:01.000 | 2021-05-21 10:54:01.000 | 51 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:53:48.000 | 2021-05-21 10:53:51.000 | 83 |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 10:54:14.000 | 2021-05-21 10:56:31.000 | 13 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:56:33.000 | 2021-05-21 10:56:38.000 | 162 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 10:58:13.000 | 2021-05-21 10:58:52.000 | 95 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 11:00:37.000 | 2021-05-21 11:00:37.000 | 105 |
| Johnny | 2021-05-21 11:03:14.000 | 2021-05-21 11:04:06.000 | 157 |
| Peter | 2021-05-21 11:05:20.000 | 2021-05-21 11:05:20.000 | 529 |

**QUESTION**

- How can I do this dynamically for each name?
- Is it possible to only look for time differences within each day? So that `Time_since_last_call` isn't calculated between days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF` and `LAG` to achieve this quite easily:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable ([Name] varchar(10),
                            CallStart datetime,
                            CallFinished datetime);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('Johnny','2021-05-21T10:52:22.000','2021-05-21T10:52:25.000'),
      ('Peter','2021-05-21T10:52:43.000','2021-05-21T10:53:10.000'),
      ('Peter','2021-05-21T10:54:01.000','2021-05-21T10:54:01.000'),
      ('Johnny','2021-05-21T10:53:48.000','2021-05-21T10:53:51.000'),
      ('Peter','2021-05-21T10:54:14.000','2021-05-21T10:56:31.000'),
      ('Johnny','2021-05-21T10:56:33.000','2021-05-21T10:56:38.000'),
      ('Johnny','2021-05-21T10:58:13.000','2021-05-21T10:58:52.000'),
      ('Johnny','2021-05-21T11:00:37.000','2021-05-21T11:00:37.000'),
      ('Johnny','2021-05-21T11:03:14.000','2021-05-21T11:04:06.000'),
      ('Peter','2021-05-21T11:05:20.000','2021-05-21T11:05:20.000');
GO
SELECT Name,
       CallStart,
       CallFinished,
       DATEDIFF(SECOND,LAG(CallFinished) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY CallStart),CallStart) AS TimeSinceLastCall
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY CallStart;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

If you don't want it to spread over days (there was no sample data with this scenario), meaning that the first call of each day (for each person) will have the value `NULL` for `TimeSinceLastCall`, then add `CONVERT(date,CallStart)` or `CAST(CallStart AS date)` to the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: Like so 

`DATEDIFF(SECOND,LAG(Call_Finished) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST([Call Start] AS date), [Name]  ORDER BY [Call Start]),[Call Start]) AS TimeSinceLastCall` ?